# Flexibly convert between string, int, double for C++ Variant Class

Tags: c++

I'm implementing a variant class (not using boost) and I'm wondering how you'd handle the case where you'd store any of string, integer, or double and automatically convert it accordingly to desired type through ToString(), ToInt(), or ToDouble().

For example,

```
Variant a = 7;
cout << "The answer is" + a.ToString() << endl; // should print "The answer is 7"
a = "7.4";
double &b = a.ToDouble();
b += 1;
cout << a.ToString() << endl; // should print 8.4
```

`ToXXX` functions should return the reference of the type that you want to convert to. Right now, I have the code where it can return the same type as it was initially assigned to( `Variant a = Int(7); a.ToInt()` works) and raise exception when the assigned type is different from the one that you want to convert to.

Sorry using boost isn't an option.

Comment: A bit hard to tell without having any idea how you are implementing it.

Comment: I have custom types `String`, `Int`, `Double` that all derives from a base object class. `a.ToDouble()` would actually return `Double` but I did override cast operator for `Double` that would actually return reference for the `double`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Sure you can. Think Boost.Any. - I suspect that the answer might be that you'd need to implement conversion to each of those types in each of the String, Int and Double classes.

Comment: @UncleBens: for some reason I assumed the string/int/double were local to the object.  I'm not sure why I assumed that.  Seems silly in hindsight.

Comment: variant is designed as a typesafe version of a union, in order to work with different types in a uniform manner, it's not intended for reinterpretation.

Comment: @GeneBushuyev shouldn't it at least be able to cast within different integer types? For example, just because `a` holds unsigned 32bit integer, it shouldn't raise an exception when you try to fetch signed 64bit int via `a.ToInt64()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    class Variant{
    public:
        Variant(){
            data.type = UNKOWN;
            data.intVal = 0;
        }
        Variant(int v){
            data.type = INT;
            data.intVal = v;
        }
        Variant(double v){
            data.type = DOUBLE;
            data.realVal = v;
        }
        Variant(std::string v){
            data.type = STRING;
            data.strVal = new std::string(v);
        }
            //the missing copy constructor
             Variant(Variant const& other)
             {
                *this = other;// redirect to the copy assignment
              }

        ~Variant(){
            if(STRING == data.type){
                delete data.strVal;
            }
        }

        Variant& operator = (const Variant& other){
            if(this != &other)
            {
                if(STRING == data.type){
                    delete data.strVal;
                }

                switch(other.data.type){
                case STRING:{
                        data.strVal = new std::string(*(other.data.strVal));
                        data.type = STRING;
                        break;
                    }
                default:{
                        memcpy(this, &other, sizeof(Variant));
                        break;
                    }           
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }
        Variant& operator = (int newVal){
            if(STRING == data.type){
                delete data.strVal;
            }
            data.type = INT;
            data.intVal= newVal;
            return *this;
        }

        Variant& operator = (double newVal){
            if(STRING == data.type){
                delete data.strVal;
            }
            data.type = DOUBLE;
            data.realVal= newVal;
            return *this;
        }

        Variant& operator = (std::string& newVal){
            if(STRING == data.type){
                delete data.strVal;
            }
            data.type = STRING;
            data.strVal= new std::string(newVal);
            return *this;
        }
        operator int&() {
            if(INT == data.type)
            {
                return data.intVal;
            }
            //do type conversion if you like
            throw std::runtime_error("bad cast");
        }

        operator double&()  {
            if(DOUBLE == data.type){
                return data.realVal;
            }
            //do type conversion if you like
            throw std::runtime_error("bad cast");
        }
        operator std::string&() {
            if(STRING == data.type){
                return *data.strVal;
            }
            throw std::runtime_error("bad cast");
        }
    private:
        enum Type{
            UNKOWN=0,
            INT,
            DOUBLE,
            STRING
        };
        struct{
            Type type;
            union 
            {
                int intVal;
                double realVal;
                std::string* strVal;
            };
        } data;
    };


    int main(){
        Variant v("this is string");//string
        v=1;//int
        v=1.0;//double
        v=std::string("another string");//
        Variant v2; //unkown type
        v2=v;//string
        std::cout << (std::string&)v2 << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: this is a simplified version from my product code. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is dangerous, it is missing a copy-constructor that mimics the assignment operator. See the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C++_programming)

Comment: @JulianRaschke you're right. it's a simplified version. We should add the copy constructor, anyway

Comment: The copy constructor is still not safe because `*this` has completely uninitialized members at the time of assignment. If `type` happens to be STRING, this will go wrong.

Answer (score 7):

To implement something like this, you need to be able to change the stored type, because if the user changes the variable by reference, he wants the change to affect the value stored, so I'd write something like this:

```
class Variant
{
private:
    enum StoreType
    {
        Integer,
        Float,
        String,
    }
    store_type;

    union
    {
       int * as_integer;
       double * as_double;
       std::string * as_string;
    }
    store_pointer;

    // convert to type
    void integer_to_double();
    void integer_to_string();
    void double_to_integer();
    void double_to_string();
    void string_to_integer();
    void string_to_double();

public:

...

    int & ToInt()
    {
        switch (store_type)
        {
            case Integer: break;
            case Double: double_to_integer(); break;
            case String: string_to_integer(); break;
        }
        return * as_integer;
    }

...

}
```

Comment: I don't think I'd recommend `String` as an `enum` value.  Most people either prefix or postfix the enum type.  `StringType` or something.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemeted a simple variant class myself (without using third-party libs). Each of the `ToXxx` functions contains a `switch` over `m_type` (enum that indicates the type currently being held). For string conversion (both from and to) I use `std::stringstream`. It's trivial, really. Pretty much like *Mooing Duck* suggested.

P. S. If frequent calling of string conversion for the same value is intended, I'd cache it.

Answer (score 2):

Just to let know that C++17 will implement an [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

First, do you absolutely need to return by reference?  Returning by value would probably be easier, since you could do that at any time without having to change the internal state of the Variant object.

If you absolutely do need to return by reference, then you need to have a valid memory location to return a reference to.  (So for example, returning a reference to a stack object is no good, because the stack object would be gone when the ToXXX() method returns, and the reference would be a reference to invalid memory)

The easy way to do that would be to include a (mutable?) member variable of each type in your Variant object, and set that member variable's value and return a reference to it as necessary.  Of course that downside of that is that it makes your Variant objects as large as the sum of all the possible objects, but that might be okay if you don't care much about memory usage.

If you do care about minimizing memory usage of your Variant objects also, then you'll probably need to use a union (or something equivalent to one).  C unions will work for POD types, but if you need to include non-POD types (e.g. std::string objects) they won't be sufficient.  If you need that, you can go with a byte-buffer (that is large enough for the largest possible type to fit into) and using placement-new and explicit destructor calls when necessary, but it is a bit fiddly to implement.

As far as the actual conversions of data types go (e.g. "7" -> (int)7 -> (double)7.0, you'll simply have to implement logic (perhaps via nested switch statements?) to do the right thing for each possible pair of "source" and "destination" types.  I don't think there is any magic way around that, short of using boost functionality where it has been done for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way I can think of, if you want to be able to do conversions on the fly.

```
class Variant {
    enum internaltype {stringtype, inttype, doubletype} curtype;
    std::string strdata; //can't be in union
    union {
        int intdata;
        double doubledata;
    };
public:
    Variant() :curtype(inttype) {}
    Variant(const std::string& s) : curtype(stringtype), strdata(s) {}
    Variant(int i) : curtype(inttype) {intdata = i;}
    Variant(double d) : curtype(doubletype) {doubledata = d;}

    std::string& ToString() {
        std::stringstream ss;
        switch(curtype) { 
        case inttype: 
                      ss << intdata;
                      ss >> stringdata;
                      break;
        case doubletype: 
                      ss << doubledata;
                      ss >> stringdata;
                      break;
        }
        curtype = stringtype;
        return &strdata;
    }
    int& ToInt() {/*much the same*/}
    double& ToDouble() {/*much the same*/}
};
```

Comment: Evan Dark's variation is smaller, and doesn't have the `union` complexities that mine has.  Do that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty implementation using [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/any.html) as the value holder instead of custom classes. As you can see, templates can help a bit to keep the amount of code somewhat shorter.

ToXXX functions change the underlying type of the stored value (unless no actual conversion is required), then return a reference to it. Conversions are done using [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html), which may not be entirely suitable for your purposes (it will throw exceptions if the conversions are not successful according to lexical_cast's very strict conditions).

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

class Variant
{
    boost::any value;
public:
    Variant(int n): value(n) {}
    Variant(double d): value(d) {}
    Variant(const std::string& s): value(s) {}
    Variant(const char* s): value(std::string(s)) {} //without this, string literals create ambiguities

    int& ToInt() { return convert<int>();}
    double& ToDouble() { return convert<double>(); }
    std::string& ToString() { return convert<std::string>(); }

private:
    template <class T>
    T& convert()
    {
        if (typeid(T) != value.type()) { //otherwise no conversion required
            if (typeid(int) == value.type()) {
                value = boost::lexical_cast<T>(boost::any_cast<int>(value));
            }
            else if (typeid(double) == value.type()) {
                value = boost::lexical_cast<T>(boost::any_cast<double>(value));
            }
            else if (typeid(std::string) == value.type()) {
                value = boost::lexical_cast<T>(boost::any_cast<std::string>(value));
            }
        }
        return *boost::any_cast<T>(&value);
    }
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Variant a = 7;
    cout << "The answer is" + a.ToString() << endl; // should print "The answer is 7"
    a = "7.4";
    double &b = a.ToDouble();
    b += 1;
    cout << a.ToString() << endl; // should print 8.4
}
```

(In action: http://codepad.org/C3l5AXg3)

The implementation might be even more straightforward with [`boost::variant<int, double, std::string>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/variant.html), as you might be able to pull it off with a single visitor with templated `operator()` instead of having to write a separate code path for each of the different types.

Comment: It's a bad idea to make `ToSomething()` functions mutating in general. Neither it's viable design approach, e.g. `Variant v("abc"); v.ToDouble();`.

Comment: @Gene: Yes, it may be a bad idea, but that's what you have to do in order to meet the requirements from the example usage code. - As to the counter-example, this will just throw an error (bad_lexical_cast, but you may catch and replace it with your own error). What else would a class designed like this do?

Comment: I'm not saying the other solutions are better, I'm saying any solution is bad because the design requirements are flawed.

Comment: @Gene: Yes, I'd agree with that.

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast<T>` won't compile on VS2010. Sadly it seems you must have an explicit target type to avoid no acceptable conversion errors.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you need I would suggest downloading http://qt.nokia.com and looking into an implementation of QVariant Class.  If that seems overly complicated I would suggest something like this:

```
class Variant
{
private:
    enum data_type {
     ...
    };

    data_type variant_type;

    union Data {
       char *string;
       int integer;
       double dbl;
    } data;

public:
    Variant(const int data);
    Variant(const double data);
    Variant(const char *data);

    //  I think that implementation of the constructors should be pretty straight forward.

    int ToInt() const; 
    double ToDouble() const; 
    std::string ToString() const;
};
```

The implementation of the conversion should be straightforward from here.

If you want it simpler and the performance is not of a major concern the data stored in the variant could be converted to a string and then converted back when the To method is called.

```
class Variant
{
private:
    char data_string[16384];

public:
    Variant(const int data);
    Variant(const double data);
    Variant(const char *data);

    //  I think that implementation of the constructors should be pretty straight forward.

    int ToInt() const; 
    double ToDouble() const; 
    std::string ToString() const;
};
```

If you need implementation details for the conversion functions I can provide them but I think that they should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Your `To`-methods should return references (and that make the whole topic a lot more complicated since changing the reference should change all the representations.)

Comment: True enough but I personally don't see a reason to make it that much more complicated then it needs to be.  The only return that a reference return would be advantageous for is strings.

Comment: You should read the question again. It is a requirement that the stored value can be changed by modified the returned reference.